# Add new column on Elixir

Tags: python, mysql, migration, python-elixir

I use Elixir as an ORM for a MySQL database. I want to add new column to my schema. 
/ 
How can I keep the original data in MySQL and update the schema automatically? The concept is called migrate in Ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [sqlalchemy-migrate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy-migrate). Elixir is a layer on top of SQLAlchemy, and sqlalchemy-migrate was inspired by RoR migrate.